# Error Inflating class android support.percent.RelativeLayout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-relativelayout, percentage

I add to the sdk Android the  support Library 23.1.1
I did: Android Tools / Add Support Library to project.
Still, Anything I try to  use layout with:  android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout..

I am getting running error: "Error Inflating class android support.percent.RelativeLayout".

Am I missing something ?
Thanks
Danny

Comment: Did you get a solution to this one?
You should be using android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks. This Issue (and other reasons) made me migrate from Eclipse to Studio. There I was able to use percentage functionality.....

Comment: I don't understand,, what is the solution

Comment: I did not solved the problem directly. Don't know the solution. Just migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio and it worked.....

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on android studio by use `23.1.1` version

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile "com.android.support:percent:23.1.1"
```